# C# HttpClient Usert Agent headers are not adding

Tags: c#, http, web, header, request

i came across strange problem. I just set User agent headers in such way:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent","Chrome/65.0.3325.181");

var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
```

But when i check it in fiddler i don't see such header. Maybe someone can explain to me what i do wrong?

Comment: I have tested with your updated question and it's showing the header I set in Fiddler just fine. [Example](https://i.imgur.com/aM967ws.jpg)

Comment: yep. Code is easy and looks like it  should  be working, but unfortunatly for it doesn't, maybe i have some problems  with fiddler how do you think?  @john

Comment: View the response of a page like [this](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-http-headers-is-my-browser-sending) which shows the headers you are sending.

Comment: Is there more to your question than what you're showing above?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue when using HttpClient. Its intended use is not super obvious. If you want to control request headers, you have to construct a HttpRequestMessage object as shown below.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();

HttpRequestMessage reqObj = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), "your uri" );
reqObj.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Chrome/65.0.3325.181");

httpClient.SendAsync(reqObj);
```